# C++ cin >> not starting again

Tags: c++, cin

Ok, so I am doing an exercise for a C++ programming book, and it asks me to make a program that I enter names and scores next to those names, and they are both saved in vectors. Then, after I am finished entering those, it will prompt me to enter a name, then it will find the corresponding score to that name. e.x. I type in "John" it returns 5 if that's what I put John's score as.

The problem I am having, is after the user is done entering the names and scores, and my program prompts the user to enter in a name (to find the corresponding score), the code just skips over the `cin` command and moves on, making my program not work. I will post the full program, then the part I need help with:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
vector<string>names;
vector<int>scores;
string name = "";
int score;
while(cin >> name &&  cin >> score)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) // checks all previous words
        {
            if(name == names[i]) // if the name is used twice, exit
            {
                cout << "Error. Terminating...\n";
                exit(4);
            }
            else;
        }

        names.push_back(name);
        scores.push_back(score);
}

cout << "Enter a name, which I will find the score for. \n";
string locateName;
while(cin >> locateName) // i think the program won't accept the locateName
{

    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(locateName == names[i])
        {
            cout << names[i] << "'s score is " << scores[i] << '\n';
        }
        else { cout << "Name not found. \n"; }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the part that is not working:

```
cout << "Enter a name, which I will find the score for. \n";
string locateName;
while(cin >> locateName)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(locateName == names[i])
        {
            cout << names[i] << "'s score is " << scores[i] << '\n';
        }
        else { cout << "Name not found. \n"; }
    }

}
```

Specifically, the `while(cin >> locateName)`. Here is some additional information: Whenever I enter the names (John 5 Bob 6 Pete 9) I press **CTRL + Z** then **ENTER** to stop the `cin`. Then the program just ends. Is this(ctrlZ) what is causing the `while(cin >> locateName)` to not accept new values? Help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Here's a hint/idea - how many times does it say "Name not found"?  Just once, or twice?  (I ask this because as you search through the loop, for each element in the loop, you'll be outputting something.  Given your example, if you look for Pete, you'll get: "Name not found. \nName not found. \nPete's score is 9\n")

Comment: Off topic suggestion: Don't split the names and the scores into two vectors make a structure that stores both and make a single vector of that structure.

Comment: @user4581301 The book's exercise says to use vectors. We haven't learned stucts yet.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Now it does not even say "Name not found." it just ends the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+Z is interpreted as an end-of-file marker.  Once `cin` sees that marker, it goes into an error state (`cin.eof()` and `cin.fail()` will be `true`, which means `(bool)cin` will be `false`, that's why your first loop stops).  While in an error state, `cin` won't accept any more input.

To get `cin` back into a good state, you can call `cin.clear()`.  Once it's back in a good state it will accept input once again.